# Problem related to forms using Models

Tags: python, django

I have `model Person` or say Profile and this `class Person` has a genericRelationship with the phonenumber class.Now I wanted to generate a ModelForm which displays the option of adding two or three contact numbers at a time in a single form. Is this possible ?
My models look like :

```
class Person(models.Model):
      """Person model"""

      title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
     first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=100)
      middle_name = models.CharField(_('middle name'), max_length=100, null=True,
          blank=True)
      last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=100, null=True,
          blank=True)
      suffix = models.CharField(_('suffix'), max_length=20, null=True,
          blank=True)

      slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), max_length=50, unique=True)

      phone_number = generic.GenericRelation('PhoneNumber')
     email_address = generic.GenericRelation('EmailAddress')
     address = generic.GenericRelation('Address')

     date_of_birth = models.DateField(_('date of birth'), null=True, blank=True)                                                                               gender = models.CharField(_('gender'), max_length=1, null=True,
         blank=True, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)


 class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
     """Phone Number model."""

     PHONE_LOCATION_CHOICES = (
        ('w', _('Work')),                                                                                                                                315         ('m', _('Mobile')),
         ('f', _('Fax')),
         ('p', _('Pager')),
         ('h', _('Home')),
         ('o', _('Other')),
     )

     content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,         limit_choices_to{'app_label': 'contacts'})
     object_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
     content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

     phone_number = models.CharField(_('number'), max_length=50)

     location = models.CharField(_('location'), max_length=1,
         choices=PHONE_LOCATION_CHOICES, default='w')

     date_added = models.DateTimeField(_('date added'), auto_now_add=True)
     date_modified = models.DateTimeField(_('date modified'), auto_now=True)
```

Then I wanted to make a form for editing the contacxt details.

I would be very thankful to yoy!
Thank You!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [**Django Doc**](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/)

> **Generic Relations :** let an object have
>   a foreign key to any object through a
>   content-type/object-id field. A
>   GenericForeignKey field can point to
>   any object, be it animal, vegetable,
>   or mineral.

This means you can do what you are saying you want to do.

**UPDATE:** Adding some code. This would be your `forms.py`

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):                              
    title     = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=30)
    phone_num1= forms.CharField(label='Phone Number1',widget=forms.TextInput())
    phone_num2= forms.CharField(label='Phone Number2',widget=forms.TextInput())
```

This could be your `views.py`. In your HTML code provide an EDIT link, which has the url in some format. This url format should be mapped in your urls.py file. Which would invoke this fn. in `views.py`.

```
if request.GET.has_key('edit'): # already there - EDIT
    nameid = request.GET['edit']
    try:
        person   = Person.objects.get(id=nameid)
        phonenum = PhoneNumber.objects.get(user=request.user, person=person)
        pnums    = ' '.join(n.phone_number for n in person.phonenum_set.all())
    except (PhoneNumber.DoesNotExist, Person.DoesNotExist):
        raise
    form = EditForm({'title:person.title, 'phonunumbers': phonenums})
```

This is the general idea. There might be some syntax errror as I am typing this in the browser...

Comment: can u write up a view for me, for the generation of form I am usin Model Form.

Comment: Infact I wanted to create a form which is to be prepopulated with the data present in the database. i.e I wanted to create an edit form for my class. Can u suggest me the view

Comment: Thanks buddy I got my work done,,,,,,,the link u suggested was a useful link

Comment: @prateek Good that you were able to solve your problem. In keeping with good practices at StackOverflow, please upvote any answer that has helped you and finally mark the 'one' answer that has helped you the most as 'correct' (green check).